Cannot get "Authorize specific nodes" tutorial working for substrate. Beginner question
I have been trying to get this working for a few days. I'd be really really appreciative if someone could help me as I just can't get it working. I am a complete beginner and not familiar with the Rust toolchain.
I followed the steps at https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/
I added the following line to runtime/Cargo.toml
pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

even though the other lines already in the file look like
pallet-aura = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", tag = "polkadot-v1.9.0", default-features = false }

which have a different version number as a tag. I also added the line to [features] as per the tutorial
When I make that change and run
cargo build --release

It appears to build ok.
Next I tried to make the changes specified in the tutorial to runtime/src/lib.rs.
Below is the file. I have added in comments here as "START OF CHANGE" to highlight on here where I have changed the file in two locations.
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[cfg(feature = "std")]
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/wasm_binary.rs"));

use pallet_grandpa::AuthorityId as GrandpaId;
use sp_api::impl_runtime_apis;
use sp_consensus_aura::sr25519::AuthorityId as AuraId;
use sp_core::{crypto::KeyTypeId, OpaqueMetadata};
use sp_runtime::{
    create_runtime_str, generic, impl_opaque_keys,
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, Block as BlockT, IdentifyAccount, NumberFor, One, Verify},
    transaction_validity::{TransactionSource, TransactionValidity},
    ApplyExtrinsicResult, MultiSignature,
};
use sp_std::prelude::*;
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
use sp_version::NativeVersion;
use sp_version::RuntimeVersion;


/// START OF CHANGE!!!!!
use frame_system::EnsureRoot;

construct_runtime!(
pub enum Runtime where
   Block = Block,
   NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
   UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
 {
   NodeAuthorization: pallet_node_authorization::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
 }
);
/// END OF CHANGE!!!

use frame_support::genesis_builder_helper::{build_config, create_default_config};
pub use frame_support::{
    construct_runtime, derive_impl, parameter_types,
    traits::{
        ConstBool, ConstU128, ConstU32, ConstU64, ConstU8, KeyOwnerProofSystem, Randomness,
        StorageInfo,
    },
    weights::{
        constants::{
            BlockExecutionWeight, ExtrinsicBaseWeight, RocksDbWeight, WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND,
        },
        IdentityFee, Weight,
    },
    StorageValue,
};
pub use frame_system::Call as SystemCall;
pub use pallet_balances::Call as BalancesCall;
pub use pallet_timestamp::Call as TimestampCall;
use pallet_transaction_payment::{ConstFeeMultiplier, CurrencyAdapter, Multiplier};
#[cfg(any(feature = "std", test))]
pub use sp_runtime::BuildStorage;
pub use sp_runtime::{Perbill, Permill};

/// Import the template pallet.
pub use pallet_template;

/// An index to a block.
pub type BlockNumber = u32;

/// Alias to 512-bit hash when used in the context of a transaction signature on the chain.
pub type Signature = MultiSignature;

/// Some way of identifying an account on the chain. We intentionally make it equivalent
/// to the public key of our transaction signing scheme.
pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;

/// Balance of an account.
pub type Balance = u128;

/// Index of a transaction in the chain.
pub type Nonce = u32;

/// A hash of some data used by the chain.
pub type Hash = sp_core::H256;

/// Opaque types. These are used by the CLI to instantiate machinery that don't need to know
/// the specifics of the runtime. They can then be made to be agnostic over specific formats
/// of data like extrinsics, allowing for them to continue syncing the network through upgrades
/// to even the core data structures.
pub mod opaque {
    use super::*;

    pub use sp_runtime::OpaqueExtrinsic as UncheckedExtrinsic;

    /// Opaque block header type.
    pub type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
    /// Opaque block type.
    pub type Block = generic::Block<Header, UncheckedExtrinsic>;
    /// Opaque block identifier type.
    pub type BlockId = generic::BlockId<Block>;

    impl_opaque_keys! {
        pub struct SessionKeys {
            pub aura: Aura,
            pub grandpa: Grandpa,
        }
    }
}

// To learn more about runtime versioning, see:
// https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/build/upgrade#runtime-versioning
#[sp_version::runtime_version]
pub const VERSION: RuntimeVersion = RuntimeVersion {
    spec_name: create_runtime_str!("solochain-template-runtime"),
    impl_name: create_runtime_str!("solochain-template-runtime"),
    authoring_version: 1,
    // The version of the runtime specification. A full node will not attempt to use its native
    //   runtime in substitute for the on-chain Wasm runtime unless all of `spec_name`,
    //   `spec_version`, and `authoring_version` are the same between Wasm and native.
    // This value is set to 100 to notify Polkadot-JS App (https://polkadot.js.org/apps) to use
    //   the compatible custom types.
    spec_version: 100,
    impl_version: 1,
    apis: RUNTIME_API_VERSIONS,
    transaction_version: 1,
    state_version: 1,
};

/// This determines the average expected block time that we are targeting.
/// Blocks will be produced at a minimum duration defined by `SLOT_DURATION`.
/// `SLOT_DURATION` is picked up by `pallet_timestamp` which is in turn picked
/// up by `pallet_aura` to implement `fn slot_duration()`.
///
/// Change this to adjust the block time.
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 6000;

// NOTE: Currently it is not possible to change the slot duration after the chain has started.
//       Attempting to do so will brick block production.
pub const SLOT_DURATION: u64 = MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK;

// Time is measured by number of blocks.
pub const MINUTES: BlockNumber = 60_000 / (MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK as BlockNumber);
pub const HOURS: BlockNumber = MINUTES * 60;
pub const DAYS: BlockNumber = HOURS * 24;

/// The version information used to identify this runtime when compiled natively.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
pub fn native_version() -> NativeVersion {
    NativeVersion { runtime_version: VERSION, can_author_with: Default::default() }
}

const NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(75);

parameter_types! {
    pub const MaxWellKnownNodes: u32 = 8;
    pub const MaxPeerIdLength: u32 = 128;
    pub const BlockHashCount: BlockNumber = 2400;
    pub const Version: RuntimeVersion = VERSION;
    /// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time.
    pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights =
        frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::with_sensible_defaults(
            Weight::from_parts(2u64 * WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND, u64::MAX),
            NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO,
        );
    pub BlockLength: frame_system::limits::BlockLength = frame_system::limits::BlockLength
        ::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;
}


/// The default types are being injected by [`derive_impl`](`frame_support::derive_impl`) from
/// [`SoloChainDefaultConfig`](`struct@frame_system::config_preludes::SolochainDefaultConfig`),
/// but overridden as needed.
#[derive_impl(frame_system::config_preludes::SolochainDefaultConfig as frame_system::DefaultConfig)]
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    /// The block type for the runtime.
    type Block = Block;
    /// Block & extrinsics weights: base values and limits.
    type BlockWeights = BlockWeights;
    /// The maximum length of a block (in bytes).
    type BlockLength = BlockLength;
    /// The identifier used to distinguish between accounts.
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    /// The type for storing how many extrinsics an account has signed.
    type Nonce = Nonce;
    /// The type for hashing blocks and tries.
    type Hash = Hash;
    /// Maximum number of block number to block hash mappings to keep (oldest pruned first).
    type BlockHashCount = BlockHashCount;
    /// The weight of database operations that the runtime can invoke.
    type DbWeight = RocksDbWeight;
    /// Version of the runtime.
    type Version = Version;
    /// The data to be stored in an account.
    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;
    /// This is used as an identifier of the chain. 42 is the generic substrate prefix.
    type SS58Prefix = SS58Prefix;
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}


// START OF CHANGE !!!!!!!!!!!
impl pallet_node_authorization::Config for Runtime {
 type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
 type MaxWellKnownNodes = MaxWellKnownNodes;
 type MaxPeerIdLength = MaxPeerIdLength;
 type AddOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
 type RemoveOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
 type SwapOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
 type ResetOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
 type WeightInfo = ();
}
/// END OF CHANGE !!!!

impl pallet_aura::Config for Runtime {
    type AuthorityId = AuraId;
    type DisabledValidators = ();
    type MaxAuthorities = ConstU32<32>;
    type AllowMultipleBlocksPerSlot = ConstBool<false>;

    #[cfg(feature = "experimental")]
    type SlotDuration = pallet_aura::MinimumPeriodTimesTwo<Runtime>;
}

impl pallet_grandpa::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;

    type WeightInfo = ();
    type MaxAuthorities = ConstU32<32>;
    type MaxNominators = ConstU32<0>;
    type MaxSetIdSessionEntries = ConstU64<0>;

    type KeyOwnerProof = sp_core::Void;
    type EquivocationReportSystem = ();
}

impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Runtime {
    /// A timestamp: milliseconds since the unix epoch.
    type Moment = u64;
    type OnTimestampSet = Aura;
    type MinimumPeriod = ConstU64<{ SLOT_DURATION / 2 }>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}

/// Existential deposit.
pub const EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT: u128 = 500;

impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    type MaxLocks = ConstU32<50>;
    type MaxReserves = ();
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
    /// The type for recording an account's balance.
    type Balance = Balance;
    /// The ubiquitous event type.
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type DustRemoval = ();
    type ExistentialDeposit = ConstU128<EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT>;
    type AccountStore = System;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_balances::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type FreezeIdentifier = ();
    type MaxFreezes = ();
    type RuntimeHoldReason = ();
    type RuntimeFreezeReason = ();
}

parameter_types! {
    pub FeeMultiplier: Multiplier = Multiplier::one();
}

impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, ()>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ConstFeeMultiplier<FeeMultiplier>;
}

impl pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_sudo::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

/// Configure the pallet-template in pallets/template.
impl pallet_template::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_template::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
#[frame_support::runtime]
mod runtime {
    #[runtime::runtime]
    #[runtime::derive(
        RuntimeCall,
        RuntimeEvent,
        RuntimeError,
        RuntimeOrigin,
        RuntimeFreezeReason,
        RuntimeHoldReason,
        RuntimeSlashReason,
        RuntimeLockId,
        RuntimeTask
    )]
    pub struct Runtime;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(0)]
    pub type System = frame_system;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(1)]
    pub type Timestamp = pallet_timestamp;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(2)]
    pub type Aura = pallet_aura;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(3)]
    pub type Grandpa = pallet_grandpa;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(4)]
    pub type Balances = pallet_balances;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(5)]
    pub type TransactionPayment = pallet_transaction_payment;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(6)]
    pub type Sudo = pallet_sudo;

    // Include the custom logic from the pallet-template in the runtime.
    #[runtime::pallet_index(7)]
    pub type TemplateModule = pallet_template;
}






/// The address format for describing accounts.
pub type Address = sp_runtime::MultiAddress<AccountId, ()>;
/// Block header type as expected by this runtime.
pub type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
/// Block type as expected by this runtime.
pub type Block = generic::Block<Header, UncheckedExtrinsic>;
/// The SignedExtension to the basic transaction logic.
pub type SignedExtra = (
    frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
    pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
);

/// All migrations of the runtime, aside from the ones declared in the pallets.
///
/// This can be a tuple of types, each implementing `OnRuntimeUpgrade`.
#[allow(unused_parens)]
type Migrations = ();

/// Unchecked extrinsic type as expected by this runtime.
pub type UncheckedExtrinsic =
    generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, RuntimeCall, Signature, SignedExtra>;
/// The payload being signed in transactions.
pub type SignedPayload = generic::SignedPayload<RuntimeCall, SignedExtra>;
/// Executive: handles dispatch to the various modules.
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    Migrations,
>;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benches {
    frame_benchmarking::define_benchmarks!(
        [frame_benchmarking, BaselineBench::<Runtime>]
        [frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>]
        [pallet_balances, Balances]
        [pallet_timestamp, Timestamp]
        [pallet_sudo, Sudo]
        [pallet_template, TemplateModule]
    );
}

impl_runtime_apis! {
    impl sp_api::Core<Block> for Runtime {
        fn version() -> RuntimeVersion {
            VERSION
        }

        fn execute_block(block: Block) {
            Executive::execute_block(block);
        }

        fn initialize_block(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) -> sp_runtime::ExtrinsicInclusionMode {
            Executive::initialize_block(header)
        }
    }

    impl sp_api::Metadata<Block> for Runtime {
        fn metadata() -> OpaqueMetadata {
            OpaqueMetadata::new(Runtime::metadata().into())
        }

        fn metadata_at_version(version: u32) -> Option<OpaqueMetadata> {
            Runtime::metadata_at_version(version)
        }

        fn metadata_versions() -> sp_std::vec::Vec<u32> {
            Runtime::metadata_versions()
        }
    }

    impl sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
        fn apply_extrinsic(extrinsic: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic) -> ApplyExtrinsicResult {
            Executive::apply_extrinsic(extrinsic)
        }

        fn finalize_block() -> <Block as BlockT>::Header {
            Executive::finalize_block()
        }

        fn inherent_extrinsics(data: sp_inherents::InherentData) -> Vec<<Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic> {
            data.create_extrinsics()
        }

        fn check_inherents(
            block: Block,
            data: sp_inherents::InherentData,
        ) -> sp_inherents::CheckInherentsResult {
            data.check_extrinsics(&block)
        }
    }

    impl sp_transaction_pool::runtime_api::TaggedTransactionQueue<Block> for Runtime {
        fn validate_transaction(
            source: TransactionSource,
            tx: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            block_hash: <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
        ) -> TransactionValidity {
            Executive::validate_transaction(source, tx, block_hash)
        }
    }

    impl sp_offchain::OffchainWorkerApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn offchain_worker(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) {
            Executive::offchain_worker(header)
        }
    }

    impl sp_consensus_aura::AuraApi<Block, AuraId> for Runtime {
        fn slot_duration() -> sp_consensus_aura::SlotDuration {
            sp_consensus_aura::SlotDuration::from_millis(Aura::slot_duration())
        }

        fn authorities() -> Vec<AuraId> {
            Aura::authorities().into_inner()
        }
    }

    impl sp_session::SessionKeys<Block> for Runtime {
        fn generate_session_keys(seed: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<u8> {
            opaque::SessionKeys::generate(seed)
        }

        fn decode_session_keys(
            encoded: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> Option<Vec<(Vec<u8>, KeyTypeId)>> {
            opaque::SessionKeys::decode_into_raw_public_keys(&encoded)
        }
    }

    impl sp_consensus_grandpa::GrandpaApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn grandpa_authorities() -> sp_consensus_grandpa::AuthorityList {
            Grandpa::grandpa_authorities()
        }

        fn current_set_id() -> sp_consensus_grandpa::SetId {
            Grandpa::current_set_id()
        }

        fn submit_report_equivocation_unsigned_extrinsic(
            _equivocation_proof: sp_consensus_grandpa::EquivocationProof<
                <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
                NumberFor<Block>,
            >,
            _key_owner_proof: sp_consensus_grandpa::OpaqueKeyOwnershipProof,
        ) -> Option<()> {
            None
        }

        fn generate_key_ownership_proof(
            _set_id: sp_consensus_grandpa::SetId,
            _authority_id: GrandpaId,
        ) -> Option<sp_consensus_grandpa::OpaqueKeyOwnershipProof> {
            // NOTE: this is the only implementation possible since we've
            // defined our key owner proof type as a bottom type (i.e. a type
            // with no values).
            None
        }
    }

    impl frame_system_rpc_runtime_api::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Nonce> for Runtime {
        fn account_nonce(account: AccountId) -> Nonce {
            System::account_nonce(account)
        }
    }

    impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentApi<Block, Balance> for Runtime {
        fn query_info(
            uxt: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::RuntimeDispatchInfo<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_info(uxt, len)
        }
        fn query_fee_details(
            uxt: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::FeeDetails<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_fee_details(uxt, len)
        }
        fn query_weight_to_fee(weight: Weight) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::weight_to_fee(weight)
        }
        fn query_length_to_fee(length: u32) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::length_to_fee(length)
        }
    }

    impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentCallApi<Block, Balance, RuntimeCall>
        for Runtime
    {
        fn query_call_info(
            call: RuntimeCall,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::RuntimeDispatchInfo<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_call_info(call, len)
        }
        fn query_call_fee_details(
            call: RuntimeCall,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::FeeDetails<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_call_fee_details(call, len)
        }
        fn query_weight_to_fee(weight: Weight) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::weight_to_fee(weight)
        }
        fn query_length_to_fee(length: u32) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::length_to_fee(length)
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    impl frame_benchmarking::Benchmark<Block> for Runtime {
        fn benchmark_metadata(extra: bool) -> (
            Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkList>,
            Vec<frame_support::traits::StorageInfo>,
        ) {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkList};
            use frame_support::traits::StorageInfoTrait;
            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            let mut list = Vec::<BenchmarkList>::new();
            list_benchmarks!(list, extra);

            let storage_info = AllPalletsWithSystem::storage_info();

            (list, storage_info)
        }

        fn dispatch_benchmark(
            config: frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkConfig
        ) -> Result<Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkBatch>, sp_runtime::RuntimeString> {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkBatch};
            use sp_storage::TrackedStorageKey;
            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            impl frame_system_benchmarking::Config for Runtime {}
            impl baseline::Config for Runtime {}

            use frame_support::traits::WhitelistedStorageKeys;
            let whitelist: Vec<TrackedStorageKey> = AllPalletsWithSystem::whitelisted_storage_keys();

            let mut batches = Vec::<BenchmarkBatch>::new();
            let params = (&config, &whitelist);
            add_benchmarks!(params, batches);

            Ok(batches)
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
    impl frame_try_runtime::TryRuntime<Block> for Runtime {
        fn on_runtime_upgrade(checks: frame_try_runtime::UpgradeCheckSelect) -> (Weight, Weight) {
            // NOTE: intentional unwrap: we don't want to propagate the error backwards, and want to
            // have a backtrace here. If any of the pre/post migration checks fail, we shall stop
            // right here and right now.
            let weight = Executive::try_runtime_upgrade(checks).unwrap();
            (weight, BlockWeights::get().max_block)
        }

        fn execute_block(
            block: Block,
            state_root_check: bool,
            signature_check: bool,
            select: frame_try_runtime::TryStateSelect
        ) -> Weight {
            // NOTE: intentional unwrap: we don't want to propagate the error backwards, and want to
            // have a backtrace here.
            Executive::try_execute_block(block, state_root_check, signature_check, select).expect("execute-block failed")
        }
    }

    impl sp_genesis_builder::GenesisBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
        fn create_default_config() -> Vec<u8> {
            create_default_config::<RuntimeGenesisConfig>()
        }

        fn build_config(config: Vec<u8>) -> sp_genesis_builder::Result {
            build_config::<RuntimeGenesisConfig>(config)
        }
    }
}

i.e. I added two blocks of code.
Now when I run ```cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release`` I get the following error
   Compiling node-template-runtime v0.0.0 (/path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v0.0.0 (/path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-aba1d93e56a479a5/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: env -u CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS -u RUSTC CARGO_TARGET_DIR="/path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target" RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP="1" RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  --cfg substrate_runtime " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release" "-Z" "build-std"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)


  --- stderr
       Locking 1 package to latest compatible version
        Adding node-template-runtime-blob v1.0.0 (/path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime)
     Compiling node-template-runtime v0.0.0 (/path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  error: no rules expected the token `your_tt_return`
     --> /path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:23:1
      |
  23  | / construct_runtime!(
  24  | | pub enum Runtime where
  25  | |    Block = Block,
  26  | |    NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  30  | |  }
  31  | | );
      | |_^ no rules expected this token in macro call
      |
     ::: /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tt-call-1.0.9/src/lib.rs:500:13
      |
  500 |               $input:ident = [{ $($tokens:tt)* }]
      |               ------------
      |
  note: while trying to match `frame_support`
     --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/frame/node-authorization/src/lib.rs:55:1
      |
  55  | #[frame_support::pallet]
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      = note: captured metavariables except for `:tt`, `:ident` and `:lifetime` cannot be compared to other tokens
      = note: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/macros-by-example.html#forwarding-a-matched-fragment> for more information
      = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::__private::tt_call` which comes from the expansion of the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-e28d0e5b76b1d1d3.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /path/to/dir/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-fabaa68c054ed97b.rmeta

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` (lib) due to 2 previous errors


The tutorial docs does not work for the newest version of temp-node.
What you need to do:

import the "pallet-node-authorization" as

pallet-node-authorization = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", tag = "polkadot-v1.9.0", default-features = false }

do other things (in Cargo.toml) as tutorial

config the "pallet-node-authorization" as tutorial

do not edit the "runtime" mod the "runtime_construct" macro. Instead of it, use the new way like


#[runtime::pallet_index(8)]
pub type NodeAuthorization = pallet_node_authorization;

Hope it will help you

Thank you so much. That worked. I spent the entire last two days frustrated and trying to find a solution. I assumed the tutorial was up to date as it was last updated only in January and most other articles I could find were even older. I really appreciate your help. I would not have been able to fix it otherwise.

Seems you mix the macro #[runtime::runtime] with construct_runtime! which is not correct.
Usually duplicate lang item is the hint for same package with different version imported which should be avoided.

Yes. Thanks. I didn't know that. I am trying to learn by first installing a basic example and I was following the steps in the tutorial.
